# Is "existence of injections / surjections" weaker than AC?

Tags: logic, set-theory, axiom-of-choice

Consider the following statements in $\newcommand{\ZF}{\sf (ZF)}\ZF$:

- (Inj) If $A, B$ are sets, then there is an injection $\iota:A\to B$, or an injection $\iota:B\to A$, or both.
- (Surj) If $A, B$ are non-empty sets, then there is a surjection $s:A\to B$, or a surjection $s:B\to A$, or both.

Clearly, (Inj) implies (Surj). Does (Inj) imply (AC)? Is (Surj) strictly weaker than (AC) or (Inj)?

Comment: What you write as Inj is Bernstein's Theorem (given any two sets $X$ and $Y$, there is either a bijection between $X$ and a subset of $Y$, or a bijection between a $Y$ and a subset of $X$). it is equivalent to the Axiom of Choice. You can see a sketch of the proof that Bernstein's Theorem implies the Well Ordering Principle in this [George Bergman Handout](https://math.berkeley.edu/~gbergman/grad.hndts/AC+Zorn+.ps).

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I know. I had to switch to a computer, searching for dupes on my phone can be taxing at time. Especially when walking on an uneven sidewalk.

Comment: Thanks for adding the second one.